# Dearpygui - Stacked bar chart not supported

Tags: python, visualization, stacked-bar-chart, dearpygui

I cant find in docs support for Bar stacked plot. I found out though that its possible to overrender bars, which requires each subsequent bar to increment previous series... Isnt there some more native way or api for stacked bar plots?

What I tried

```
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg

def save_callback():
    print("Save Clicked")

dpg.create_context()
dpg.create_viewport()
dpg.setup_dearpygui()

with dpg.window(label="Example Window"):

    with dpg.tree_node(label="Bar Series"):

        with dpg.plot(label="Bar Series", height=400, width=-1):

            dpg.add_plot_legend()

            # create x axis
            dpg.add_plot_axis(dpg.mvXAxis, label="Student", no_gridlines=True)
            dpg.set_axis_limits(dpg.last_item(), 9, 33)
            dpg.set_axis_ticks(dpg.last_item(), (("S1", 10), ("S2", 20), ("S3", 30)))

            # create y axis
            with dpg.plot_axis(dpg.mvYAxis, label="Score"):
                dpg.set_axis_limits(dpg.last_item(), 0, 200)
                dpg.add_bar_series([10, 20, 30], [100+50, 75+50, 90+38], label="Second", weight=1)
                dpg.add_bar_series([10, 20, 30], [100,    75,    90], label="First", weight=1)

dpg.show_viewport()
dpg.start_dearpygui()
dpg.destroy_context()
```